# Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath()) from dropdown.SelectedValue

Tags: c#, server.mappath

I have a photo gallery that with different sets in different folders. Currently i have a different page for each set. What I want to do is use a dropdown to choose which set to display. I'm using

```
Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/path/to/photos"))
```

to get all the files from the folder but I can't figure out how to get a variable to work in place of the path. Here is the original code from one of the sets pages

```css
<div class="gallery">
 <div class="row">
            @{foreach (var imgPath in Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/photos/halloween"), "*.jpg"))
                { var img = new FileInfo(imgPath);
                    <div class="col-lg-3" style="margin-top:50px">
                        <div id="thumb">

                            <a href="@Href("~/photos/halloween", Path.GetFileName(imgPath))" data-title="Halloween" data-lightbox="Halloween">
                                <img src="@Url.Content(String.Format("~/photos/halloween/{0}", img.Name))" class="img.thumbnail" height="160px" />
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
            }
        </div>
    </div>
```

im trying to do something like

```
foreach (var imgPath in Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/photos/" + album.selectedValue + "/"), " *.jpg"))
```

or

```
string albumPath = ("~/photos/" + album.selectedValue);
                    foreach (var imgPath in Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath(albumPath), " *.jpg"))
```

I keep getting the error that the variable (within the MapPath) does not exist in the current context. I've tried declaring them in the model and controller. Is there a way to get this working or is there a better way to do this?

Below are the view, controller and model of what I currently trying to get working

View

```css
@model IEnumerable<WebsiteMVC.Models.GalleryModel>
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Halloween";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/lightbox.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <head>
        <link href="~/Content/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <style>
            #thumb {
                max-height: 200px;
                max-width: 200px;
            }
        </style>

    </head>

    <div class="container">
        <h2>Halloween 2016</h2>
        <div>
            @Html.DropDownList("album", new List<SelectListItem>
           {
               new SelectListItem { Text ="Halloween", Value="halloween" },
new SelectListItem { Text ="Winter Dance", Value="winterdance" },
new SelectListItem { Text ="Winter Concert", Value="winterconcert" },
new SelectListItem { Text ="Family Work Day", Value="famworkday" },
new SelectListItem { Text ="Valentine's Day", Value="valentinesday" },
new SelectListItem { Text ="Read Across America", Value="readacrossam" },
new SelectListItem { Text ="Family Fitness Night", Value="fitness" },
new SelectListItem { Text ="Aladdin", Value="Aladdin" },
new SelectListItem { Text ="Wizards Game", Value="Wizards" },
new SelectListItem { Text ="Miscellaneous", Value="misc" }
           }, "Select Album", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }, @onchange = "this.form.submit();", ID = "album" })
        </div>


        <div class="gallery">


            <div class="row">
                
                @{string albumPath = ("~/photos/" + album.selectedValue);
                    foreach (var imgPath in Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath(albumPath), " *.jpg"))
                    {
                        var img = new FileInfo(imgPath);


                        <div class="col-lg-3" style="margin-top:50px">
                            <div id="thumb">

                                <a href="@Href("~/photos/halloween", Path.GetFileName(imgPath))" data-title="Halloween" data-lightbox="Halloween">
                                    <img src="@Url.Content(String.Format("~/photos/halloween/{0}", img.Name))" class="img.thumbnail" height="160px" />
                                </a>

                            </div>
                        </div>

                    }
                }


            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

controller

```css
        public ActionResult Gallery(string Album, string albumPath)
        {
            //albumPath = ("~/photos/" + Album);
            return View();



        }
```

and Model

```css
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebsiteMVC.Models
{
    public class GalleryModel
    {
        public string Album { get; set; }
        public string albumPath { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: I added in the full code. Yes album is the dropdown

Comment: Tell us what variable does not exist in the current context. Tell us the name of the variable. Tell us where.

Comment: in this case... "the name 'album' does not exist in the current context"

Answer (score 1):

First, you are not returning a model object to the view inside your controller. You need to instantiate your model class, set its properties, and then pass it to the View() method.

```
public ActionResult Gallery(string Album, string albumPath)
{
    GalleryModel model = new GalleryModel();
    model.albumPath = ("~/photos/" + Album);
    return View(model);
}
```

Next, you're defining your view's model as an `IEnumerable` of `GalleryModel`

```
@model IEnumerable<WebsiteMVC.Models.GalleryModel>
```

This makes the view expect a collection of objects. In your case it appears you just want a single gallery displayed in your view, so your @model definition should look like this.

```
@model WebsiteMVC.Models.GalleryModel
```

Now you can access properties in your `GalleryModel` from your view, so you can pass the `albumPath` from your model into `Server.MapPath`

```
foreach (var imgPath in Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath(Model.albumPath), "*.jpg"))
```

Note the usage of `Model.albumPath` to access the `albumPath` property on your model.

Finally, you gave these two examples which were not working:

```
foreach (var imgPath in Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/photos/" + album.selectedValue + "/"), " *.jpg"))

string albumPath = ("~/photos/" + album.selectedValue);
foreach (var imgPath in Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath(albumPath), " *.jpg"))
```

In both of these, you're attempting to use the `album` variable, which has not been defined anywhere. If you meant to use the `Album` property on your model, you'd need to use `Model.Album`.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far, I made the changes and it is storing the proper path into "Model.albumPath" when I select from the dropdown list. Now I just cant get it to load the images onto the page. I put a breakpoints on the "foreach" line and the "var img =..." but it never breaks at "var img =...". It's not going into the loop.

Comment: @EricF I notice in the second parameter of `Directory.GetFiles` you're passing `" *.jpg"` (note the space before the *). I suspect you want to just pass `"*.jpg"` to get all jpg files in that directory. I'll update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: good catch. It is going into the loop now but I an getting the error "...' is a physical path, but a virtual path was expected." so "albumPath" is getting the correct virtual path but "ImgPath" is getting the physical path of the image.

Comment: The paths returned by `Directory.GetFiles` will be physical paths, not virtual paths, so there is no need to call `Server.MapPath` on the `imgPath` value. Can you share the specific line of code that is throwing this error?

Comment: I get the error on 'var img = new FileInfo(imgPath);'  what I don't understand is that I'm using the same code currently with the exception that I have a static location i.e. '~/photos/halloween' instead of trying to use the variable 'albumPath' and its working.

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger to step through the code and see what value the `albumPath` variable has at the time the error occurs? If it works for a hard-coded location, I would suspect the variable does not have the correct value.

Comment: in the `foreach (var imgPath.....` line `Model.albumPath` is `~/photos/` which is correct but when it gets to `var img = new FileInfo(imgPath);` i get the error.  in both the variable version and the hard coded version at `var img = new FileInfo(imgPath);` `imgPath` is a physical path not virtual but it only gives the error in the variable version.

Answer (score 1):

'HERE IS THE SAMPLE OF DISPLAYING TO GRIDVIEW USING VIRTUAL PATH apply it inside the button or using sub procedures

```
If Not IsPostBack Then
            Dim filePaths() As String = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("/UploadedFiles/" + lblfullname.Text))
            Dim files As List(Of ListItem) = New List(Of ListItem)
            For Each filePath As String In filePaths
                files.Add(New ListItem(Path.GetFileName(filePath), filePath))
            Next
            GridView1.DataSource = files
            GridView1.DataBind()
        End If
```